# What are some subtle problems that can cause the restoration of a backup to fail?

Tags: backup, snapshot

There is a lot of research about why backup fail but I have trouble to find good resource about why backup **recovery** fail. Have you ever experienced recovery fail ? What are subtle issue you didn't anticipate (environment change, storage unavailability, permission, media malfunctions,...) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-exhaustive list of problems that could compromise the restoration of data:

**Human error** (probably the most common mistake)

- Wrong backup configuration
- Wrong business data target

**Backup software failure**

- breaking change between version
- internal error at restoration
- silent backup failure

**Hardware dependency**

- minimum space requirement
- minimum compute power (ram speed and memory, cpu frequency, cpu core, gpu,...)
- specific hardware requirement (gpu nvidia, cpu intel, cpu architecture, sound card)
- input/output interface requirement (mdi, usb, DVD/CD, optical, jack 3.5, Gigabyte ethernet,...)

**Network dependency**

- snapshots media available
- the medium is not accessible
- the medium is not readable (media failure)
- authentication & authorization fail
- recover endpoint is not available

**Operating system dependency**

- os type (linux, darwin, windows,...)
- os version (ubuntu 16.06 LTS, debian buster, windows home,...)
- minimum security patch, kernel version
- platform architecture (32/64bit)
- specific driver requirement (nvidia drivier, controller SATA,...)
- specific system application (hyper-v, nvidia CUDA, etc...)
- timezone, region
- user & group permission, file & folder permission
- firewall rules (port, protocol,...)

**Application dependency**

- dependency with other application & data
- application version
- incompatibility with other application
- application license status (expiration, validity, number available,...)
- application availability (can I download it now ?)